# Is it possible to combo Spy and Wishing Well?

Tags: dominion, dominion-intrigue

From the entry for [Wishing Well](http://dominionstrategy.com/2010/12/07/intrigue-wishing-well/) on [Dominion Strategy](http://dominionstrategy.com), I quote:

> Cards that you view with Spy get drawn by the Wishing Well instead of being wished for.

The cards in question are these:

[image: Wishing Well]
[image: Spy]

But as I understand it, after you play Spy, you know what the top card is (if you don't discard it), but this is drawn immediately from Wishing Well, and then you don't know what to wish for.

Am I misunderstanding how these cards work, or is the article referring to something else?

Comment: The answer to this question is why Wishing Well tends to be such a weak card in virtually any set. I still don't know why they printed it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. You are just misinterpreting the article.

You would need something like Scout to combo more effectively. Draw 4 cards, at least two non-victory, put them back, draw one using WW and wish for the second.

Comment: Aaaah! I should interpret it as "Instead of being able to wish for the card from Spy, you draw it." Thanks!

Comment: It is subtle, really. I interpreted "get drawn [..] instead of being wished for" as you don't _need to wish_, you can just draw it.

Comment: Belated note: Mystic, from the Dark Ages expansion, only has the "Wish for a card" (along with +$2), so you *can* use a Spy followed by a Mystic for a guaranteed draw if you want.

Answer (score 5):

Remember - act out the card in order that it is written:

**+1 Card**, then **+1 Action**, *then* "Name a card...".

So any card that has you put (just) one card back on your deck (e.g. Spy, Bureaucrat, Lookout, Courtyard, Pearl Diver, etc.) will not be a good combo for Wishing well.

**Scout**, **Navigator**, and **Apothecary** are good for this.